# Vector Parallelogram General Law

Tags: vectors

> Points $A,B,$ and $C$ have position vectors
>   $$A = \left[\begin{array}{cc}a\\b\\c\end{array}\right]$$
>   $$B = \left[\begin{array}{cc}d\\e\\f\end{array}\right]$$
>   $$C = \left[\begin{array}{cc}g\\h\\i\end{array}\right]$$
>   Find the position vector for point $D$ such that $ABCD$ is a parallelogram.

I have been able to do it when numbers are given for $a$ to $i$, but am struggling in this case.

Comment: What did you do when numbers are given? It's exactly the same method...

Comment: Hint: since $ABCD$ is a parallelogram, the vector D-A is equal to vector C-B, in other words, $D-A = C-B \implies D = A+C-B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notation: $IJ$ denotes the vector from point $I$ to point $J$. $O$ is the origin.

You would like to find $OD$. You have $OA$, $OB$, and $OC$. Now simply note that $AB=DC$ and $BC=AD$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Does the naming of the points not matter in the $AB = DC$ and $BC = AD$ statement?

Comment: @StopReadingThisUsername The only constraint is that the parallelogram is made up of vectors connected to each other as $A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C  \rightarrow D$. Try drawing it, then it should become quite clear. :)

Comment: Thank you for your time! I really appreciate it!